# Not able to register click listener on a marker in Google Maps v3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

Actually i am migrating from Maps v2 to v3. But i am facing a really weird error.
Here is my code

```
function createMarker(arrayPos,title,posn) {
    var size = {width:15,height:15};
    var iconSize = new google.maps.Size(size.width,size.height);
    var iconAnchor = new google.maps.Point(9, 34);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage("my.png",iconSize,null,iconAnchor),
        title: title,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        position: posn
    });
    marker.html = getMarkerHtml(arrayPos);
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();  
    infowindow.setContent(marker.html);
    infowindow.open(map,marker);
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.setContent(marker.html);
        infowindow.open(map,marker);
    });
    return marker;
}
```

In this i was experimenting opening the infowindow as soon as markers are added and also on the click listener. In this all the infowindow opens but the listerner is not registered on the first marker always. Any pointers in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified your code as following and it works. Would you check whether it solves your issue?

In order to simulate a marker click you should add: `google.maps.event.trigger(marker, 'click');`

```
function createMarker(arrayPos,title,posn) {
    var size = {width:15,height:15};
    var iconSize = new google.maps.Size(size.width,size.height);
    var iconAnchor = new google.maps.Point(9, 34);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage("my.png",iconSize,null,iconAnchor),
        title: title,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        position: posn
    });
    //marker.html = getMarkerHtml(arrayPos);
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();  
    //infowindow.setContent(marker.html);
    //infowindow.open(map,marker);

    var markersHTML = getMarkerHtml(arrayPos);

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, markersHTML) {
        return function() {
            infowindow.setContent(markersHTML);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
    })(marker, markersHTML));

    return marker;
}
```

Example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
        <title>Google Maps</title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false&language=en"> </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            var cityList = [
                    ['Chicago', 41.850033, -87.6500523, 1],
                    ['Illinois', 40.797177,-89.406738, 2]
                ],
                demoCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(41,-87),
                map;

            function initialize()
            {
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
                   zoom: 7,
                   center: demoCenter,
                   mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                 });
            }

            function addMarkers()
            {
                var marker, 
                i,
                infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

                for (i = 0; i < cityList.length; i++) 
                {  
                    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: new google.maps.LatLng(cityList[i][1], cityList[i][2]),
                        map: map,
                        title: cityList[i][0]
                    });

                    var markersHTML = ["<div><a href=\"test\">",cityList[i][0],"</a></div>"].join("");

                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, markersHTML) {
                        return function() {
                            infowindow.setContent(markersHTML);
                            infowindow.open(map, marker);
                        }
                    })(marker, markersHTML));
                }
            }

            $(document).ready(function() {
                initialize();
            });

            $(document).on('click', '.add-markers', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                addMarkers();
            });

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="basic-map">
            <div id="map_canvas" style="height:350px;"></div>
            <a href="#" class="add-markers">Add Some Markers</a>
        </div>      
    </body>
</html>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I just checked, it is not working. Actually i think so its some maps issue. Because all the marker in a particular region in the map are not getting clicked only...

Comment: Hi Mate... Thats working... But strangely in my application i am not even getting the lats for a region on map on click of it... Its strange

Comment: The google.maps.event.trigger(marker, 'click'); is needed in order to simulate a marker click.

Comment: Thank you my friend... Because of ur this sample i was able to sort out the problem.Love you :). The Issue was in my div.gmnoprint css. It was modified by some one and i got it now. Thank you mate. :D